# Dump a process memory to file / recreate process from dump file

Tags: c#, c++, assembly, il, unsafe

Just curious, maybe someone knows a way:

Is it possible, while having an opened process (app domain), dump its entire memory space to a file, send it by wire to a LAN workstation and recreate the process as it was on the first computer.

Assumptions:

- the application exists on both computers;
- the process is not creating any local settings/temporary files;
- the OS is the same on both computers;

Comment: Why do you need that ? is just for fun or you really have to do smth like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do so, you have to ensure you have the same environment to run the "dumped" process. Some of them:

- You have to provide the same handles with the same state (process, threads, file, etc.)
- The new environment must have the same memory addresses allocated (including runtime allocations) as previous had
- All the libraries must be initialized and put in the same state
- If you have some GUI interface even GPU must be in the same state (you have to preload all graphic resources etc.)
- And many more stuff to take care about.

Comment: Just in case you wish to debug that other program, on Linux/Unix the other program can be made to create core dump with 'kill'-command (I vaguely recall there's a way to do it without terminating the program), sending the core-file to the other machine and running gdb with that core file (you need to have exactly the same program binaries).

Comment: I think the same works with Windows, but I don't know how the 'core' is produced there. I recall WinDbg can handle the dumps as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's involved on Linux:

http://www.cs.iit.edu/~scs/psfiles/dsn08_dccs.pdf

Not exactly easy.